# NSArray is not saving in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I am making a high score manager.

I load and save as follows:

```
-(void)load
{
    NSMutableArray* scores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:HIGH_SCORE_KEY]];

    if(scores == nil)
    {
        highscores = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    else
    {
        highscores = scores;
    }
}


-(void)save
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highscores forKey:HIGH_SCORE_KEY];
}
```

I am storing HighScore objects:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HighScore : NSObject
{
    int score;
    NSString* name;
}

-(int)score;
-(NSString*)name;
-(id)init;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)playerName andScore:(int)playerScore; 
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
-(BOOL)isLessThan:(id)object;
@end
```

There is nothing particularly complex about this class. However, when I load, the load does not return nil but returns an empty array, indicating to me that serializing probably failed for some reason.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: gotta call synchronize on NSUserDefaults to write it back to disk

Comment: @GradyPlayer No you don't. That will happen automatically.

Comment: http://nsuserdefaults-in-iphone-sdk.blogspot.in/2013/01/save-and-retrieve-custom-object-from.html   try this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults always returns immutable objects, even if the original object was mutable. It's in the documentation for objectForKey:

The returned object is immutable, even if the value you originally set was mutable.

You will need to create a copy of the returned object before you modify it, using [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]

Probably also best to use the arrayForKey method of NSUserDefaults if you're retrieving an array. Docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can only store objects in NSUserDefaults. **So you have to convert the array to an NSArray.** However, NSArrays also only store objects, so you need to store the long values encapsulated in an NSNumber object:

```
//saving
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *arrayObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

long *arr;
arr = new long [10];

for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    [arrayObj addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:arr[i]]];
}

[standardDefaults setObject:arrayObj forKey:@"longArray"];
[arrayObj release];


//reading
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayObj = [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"longArray"];

long *arr;
arr = new long [10];

for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    arr[i] = [(NSNumber*)[arrayObj objectAtIndex:i] longValue];
}
```

Comment: What? `NSUserDefaults` has several methods for storing simple types like `BOOL` and `int`, not just objects. And `NSArray` is an object. Your answer has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is that `NSUserDefaults` only allows a few very specific objects and the OP's custom class isn't one of them.

Comment: Huh? I know what an object is. I'm pointing out mistakes in your answer. The very first sentence you posted is incorrect. `NSUserDefaults` can store a small specific set of object types as well as several non-object types. And your statement that "you have to convert the array to an `NSArray` make no sense. The array already is an `NSArray` (`NSMutableArray` is an `NSArray`). But all of this is a side issue anyway. Your answer has nothing at all to do with the problem as I stated. How does your answer help the OP? How does it help him store his custom objects properly?

Comment: I don't think you are actually reading my comments. The update you made, while true, has nothing to do with the comments I've made. You stated: *"You can only store objects in NSUserDefaults"*. This is false. You can store primitive types too. You stated: *"So you have to convert the array to an NSArray"*. No you don't. The existing `NSMutableArray` is already an `NSArray`. You can store a mutable array. Of course it will be immutable when you read it back. Lastly, your answer doesn't tell the OP how to solve the problem of storing a custom object in `NSUserDefaults`.